# How to model Hidden markov model with changing transition probability

Tags: classification, hidden-markov-model, baum-welch

I have a series of observations that fall into two outcomes, 0 or 1. These observations have an associated time of observation, as well as additional features that I can gather for that observation. I am modeling this as having two hidden states A and B, where both have some probability of observing 0 or 1, and have some unknown transition probability between states. This transition probability varies with time and is correlated with the observation features.

How would I go about modeling this? My experience with HMM is with fixed transition probabilities (e.g. with Viterbi algorithm). Given a new observation, I want to be able to predict the hidden state as well as the transition probability. I would also want to generalize this model/use it as a prior for other similar models, each with different sets of observations.

Edit: I have discovered that what I am looking for is a variant of Baum-Welch that uses other feature data besides different sequences. How can I use my additional data in the prediction of the states?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hidden Markov Model and volatile Matrix A](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/hidden-markov-model-and-volatile-matrix-a)

Comment: please see if my answer is helpful for above link. I would recommend not to do this because you might have overfitting problem

Comment: @hxd1011 interesting. what's your experience with these models? what have you used them on?

Comment: @Taylor for some human behavior modeling in cyber security research.

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly and the transition probability changes according to the time you have spend in each state, could [Hidden Semi-Markov Models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_semi-Markov_model) be another solution?

Answer (score 4):

What you are after I believe is a maximum entropy the (i.e. logistic regression) Markov model. I.e. you predict the transition probability using logistic regression on previous state and observations. There is apparently a way of training these without knowing the hidden states… I guess by expectation maximisation.

Comment: yeah EM via Baum-Welch https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum-entropy_Markov_model

Answer (score 0):

> This transition probability varies with time and is correlated with the observation features.

Another option is to use a plain old [factor graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_graph), which is a generalization of a hidden markov model. You can model the domain knowledge that results in changing transition probability as a random variable for the shared factor.